# Update just one settable item on set type column?

Tags: mysql, set

My problem is: I need enable/disable a specific item of set type column on MySQL using only SQL, without lose previous data.

**Pseudo-example:**

```
    UPDATE `table`
    SET `setlist` = TOGGLE_SET(`setlist`, 'option_a`, true)
    WHERE `id` = 1
    LIMIT 1
```

***Obs.:** TOGGLE_SET(column data, string option, bool mode) is a fake method, don't exists, is just for understand.*

**Create example:**

```
    CREATE TABLE `table` (
        `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `setlist` SET('option_a', 'option_b') NULL DEFAULT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    )
    ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

**Insert example:**

```
    INSERT INTO `table` (`id`, `setlist`) VALUES (1, 'option_b');
```

**Similar update example:**

```
    UPDATE `table`
    SET `setlist` = 'option_a,option_b'
    WHERE `id` = 1
    LIMIT 1
```

It's all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
set setlist=if(setlist is null, 'option_a', concat(setlist,',option_a'));
```

ps - column `id` is unique, `limit 1` is superfluous

Comment: Great "PS", thanks. And if I want to disable some option? For instance, do a toggle: if On, set Off, if Off, set On.

Comment: oh, then u can expand the `IF` to something like `SWITCH` or multiple `IF ELSE IF ELSE` (quiet killing and hard to maintain)

Comment: There is no native method of MySQL to resolve this? It seems that the type "set" is patternless.

Answer (score 0):

use `CONCAT_WS` so you don't have to check for NULL or add a comma to the string

```
UPDATE table SET setlist = CONCAT_WS(",", setlist, "option");
```

or if you `option` is the *third* element in your setlist use the bit with a bitwise OR

```
UPDATE table SET setlist = setlist | 4;
```

if you want to remove it, use bitwise AND with inverted bitset

```
UPDATE table SET setlist = setlist &~ 4;
```

and if you want to toggle `option` on/off, use bitwise XOR

```
UPDATE table SET setlist = setlist ^ 4;
```